# PHP trait with shared trait in class as well as trait

Tags: php, traits

How to handle a generic trait which gets added to a trait but it also used in a class so the class has access to that trait as well.

The example will throw a

> Trait method parseError has not been applied, because there are
> collisions with other trait methods

For example

```
trait customError
{
    function parseError()
    {
    }
}

trait api
{
    use customError;
    function callAPI()
    {
        $this->parseError();
    }
}

class makeAPICall
{
    use api, customError;

    function addABook($title)
    {
        $this->callAPI();
    }
    function validateBook()
    {
        $this->parseError();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've renamed error to customError as this was a bad example of name use

Comment: `error` is a reserved word, you can't name a trait that. Other than that, this code will work fine in PHP 7.3+. The error message you posted is coming from a version prior to 7.2, which is past end of life.

Comment: As the error says, the name is already in use. You need to alias it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: Ok this is an example `error` was a bad example.

Comment: You can deffinatly use a trait inanother trait :)

Comment: My PHP version is 7.2 :| thank you @AlexHowansky

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP 7.2 is pretty outdated. Support has ended in Nov 2020, and you should plan to update your system

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you change the name of `error` because that's a reserved word, this code works fine for PHP 7.3 and later. Prior to 7.3, you will need to remove the explicit `use customError` in the class definition, it's not needed because it gets included automatically by the other `use` statement:

Prior to PHP 7.3:

```
class makeAPICall
{
    use api;
}
```

7.3+:

```
class makeAPICall
{
    use api, customError;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://3v4l.org/SNjRbf).